# Paradox definition of a function and its domain

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, terminology, definition, nonlinear-optimization

I am currently reading and working through a chapter of "Convex analysis and nonlinear optimizations" by Borwein and Lewis (Chapter 3). At the beginning of the chapter I came across this definition of a domain:

> [Let $E$ be an arbitrary euclidian space.] The *domain* of a function $f:E \rightarrow (\infty,+\infty]$ is the set $$\text{dom}f=\{x \in E | f(x)<+\infty\}.$$

Now, there are two things that I do not understand.
First, a function is defined as $f:E \rightarrow (\infty,+\infty]$. So its domain is $E$. Why would I define the domain again but different? Am I unaware of another use of the name "domain"?
Second, isn't the interval $(\infty,+\infty]$ (the codomain of $f$) just the empty set?

Comment: Shouldn't the target space be $(-\infty,\infty]$?

Comment: The notation given there is generally a bit sloppy, but typically $f$ is defined only on a _subset_ of $E$; the domain is the places where $f$ is well-defined. For instance, the function $f(x)=1/x$ on the reals is usually taken to have domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, but we still often write $f: \mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is common in convex analysis to talk about "proper" domain. Most of the interesting stuff happens there.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you

Comment: @OliverDiaz Good to know

Comment: It is ingrained terminology. Rockafellar refers to it as the effective domain.

Comment: @copper.hat has exactly the right point. It is unfortunate, the Bourbaki people will not be happy, but that is what it is is. The same is true for the domain of the sub differential operator where technically the domain is the whole space, but it is used to designate the set of vectors $x$ where $\partial f(x)\neq\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

It should be $(-\infty,+\infty]$ and this set is not empty; it is the set $\Bbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$. And here “domain” has two meanings (not a good idea, if you ask me). Originally, $f$ is a function from $E$ to $(-\infty,+\infty]$ (so, $E$ is the domain of $f$). And then the author says that the domain of $f$ is the set of those $x\in E$ such that $f(x)\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: This is more like the comment. I does not add anything more than what Steven said for example.

Comment: Thank you. However the interval should not be $(-\infty,\infty]$ I think because the "wrong" interval is used several times in a function definition. It would be a very bad coincidence if they have the wrong codomain in three or so propositions.